# Border length property CSS

Tags: css, border

I'm currently working on a splash page for my website and need help with the border which I want to run underneath the main text which will be centred on the page. At the moment when I set the border to run 800px it stays left-aligned with the text above so it isn't even. I'm new to CSS and any help is appreciated. Here is my code:

```
#logo
{
width: 800px;
position: relative;
top: 150px;
left: 250px;
border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#logo {
  display:block; /* Unless it already is */
  width: 800px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: I think `margin: 150px auto 0` matches the original intent more closely.

Comment: Touche. To the OP: the margin shorthand is TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT. Omitting BOTTOM and LEFT means TOP and RIGHT will repeat for their opposite sides.

Comment: I indented the text using text-indent to solve this in the end. Thanks for your replies.